# JavaScript WebSocket replace reference with new socket

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm trying to reconnect a websocket automatically with a function.
I want it to keep the same variable name, but i'm having some issues.
here is the function I'm using

```
function reconnect(obj){
    try{
        obj=new WebSocket(obj.url);
        }
     except{
        setTimeout(reconnect,5000,obj);
    }
}

mysocket=new Websocket(myurl);
mysocket.close()
reconnect(mysocket)
```

After the reconnect function runs successfully but `mysocket` is still referenced to the old closed `Websocket`.  I'm not sure how to transfer to new `Websocket` object to the old variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding the variable. There are multiple ways to do it, quickest would be to pass an object.

```
function reconnect(obj){
    var mySocket = obj.mySocket;
    try {
        obj.mySocket=new WebSocket(mySocket.url);
    }
    except {
        setTimeout(reconnect, 5000, obj);
    }
}

mysocket=new Websocket(myurl);
mysocket.close()
var wrapperObject = {mysocket};
reconnect(wrapperObject);
// At any point of time `wrapperObject.mysocket` will have the latest socket instance
```

A more cleaner approach would be to define a wrapper `class/function` which scopes the `mySocket` variable privately. EX:

```
function ReconnectSocket (mySocket) {
    this.mySocket = mySocket
}

ReconnectSocket.prototype.reconnect = function () {
    try {
        this.mySocket = new WebSocket(this.mySocket.url);
    }
    except {
        setTimeout(reconnect, 5000);
    }
}

ReconnectSocket.prototype.getSocket = function () {
    return this.mySocket
}

var mysocket=new Websocket(myurl);
mysocket.close()
var reconnectSocket = new ReconnectSocket(mysocket).reconnect()
// `reconnectSocket.getSocket()` will give the latest instance at any point of time
```

Answer (score 0):

First approach is using global variable

```
    function reconnect(){
        try{
            mysocket=new WebSocket(mysocket.url);
            }
         except{
            setTimeout(reconnect,5000);
        }
    }

    mysocket=new Websocket(myurl);
    mysocket.close()
    reconnect()
```

Second approach, I think you should wrap your socket in a object

```
    function reconnect(obj){
        try{
            obj.mysocket=new WebSocket(obj.mysocket.url);
            }
         except{
            setTimeout(reconnect,5000,obj);
        }
    }

    var socketObject = {};
    socketObject.mysocket=new Websocket(myurl);
    socketObject.mysocket.close()
    reconnect(socketObject)
```

Comment: The second approach will throw an error, `socketObject ` has not been initialised to an object.

Comment: I thought about your first version, but if it fails on the first pass and uses the `setTimeout` won't it fail to be assigned to `mysocket`?

Comment: @jeffpkamp I'm not sure about your comment because I don't have your test environment. However I think If It fails on the first pass by problem related to Websocket itself, It may fail on `setTimeout` too but this not related to code logic. It all about your `Websocket` initialization. You should better test to know which work for you